# VBA Copy image from worksheet to Userform

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to runtime copy image from worksheet to userform image control? 
I got a shape on a worksheet containing image. And when I select --> copy (ctrl + C) this shape, go to the `UserForm1` design --> `image1` properties I can do ctrl + v in the picture property of `image1` and the image is pasted from clipboard to `image1` control. 
 
How can I achieve this using VBA in runtime? 

 
I tried `UserForm1.Image1.Picture = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Picture`
And many similar bot none of them work 
 
I usually get "Object doesn't support this property or method" or "Type mismatch"

Comment: If you use an ActiveX image control on the worksheet, you can directly assign its picture to the one on the form. For other pictures, search for Stephen Bullen's PastePicture code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago I was looking for a solution of the same problem. Did not find a solution, but I found a great workaround:

1. Make a separate form with plenty of pictures in it. Name it `user_form_pics`.
2. Then call the following on your form:

`Me.Image1.Picture = user_form_pics.img_name11.Picture`

This is how to use it in the constructor:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Image1.Picture = user_form_pics.img_name11.Picture
End Sub
```

It works! Now your form has the picture of the `user_form_pics.img_name11`

Edit:
In case that you need to save Chart to picture, the procedure is the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim chtChart    As Chart
    Dim strPath     As String

    Set chtChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\myChart.bmp"

    chtChart.Export (strPath)

    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
    UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(strPath)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks guys but i forgot to mention. I have no problem in copying from ActiveX control or from other image control on userform.
The problem is that Picture I want to copy is a shape. It's created by copying Chart and pasting it to worksheet. I got the shape name and everything else. I can select this shape and so on. I just can't copy picture from it and paste it to 'UserForm.Image.Picture' property

Comment: @Sphinx - in this case, you should save the picture of the chart as a bmp on the same folder as the Excel Application. Then refer to it, using its Path and its name. Or at least this was something I used to do...

Comment: @Sphinx - see the edited answer to get what I mean :)

Comment: Yes I know this routine too. I just thought that there is some simple way to copy picture from shape to Image control. Like copying from ActiveX Image control on sheet. Anyway there has to be a way to do this if it's possible to paste the image from clipboard directly to "Picture"  property on form design. Thanks Vityata.